# Java: generate random String with (Button)

Tags: java, android

My code was running good, but just one times. I need repeating when ===> `ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);`
Is click.

This is the code

```
String questionNumber = "";
EditText answer;
Button ok;
TextView question;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewQuestion);

    Random random = new Random();
    questionNumber = String.format("%04d",random.nextInt(10000));
    question.setText(questionNumber);


    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (answer.getText().toString().equals(questionNumber)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Input True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: what is the code that you want to repeat ??

Comment: it's just like quizz, and i just make itu once, but i want to reload when Button 'ok' is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this..

```
String questionNumber = "";
EditText answer;
Button ok;
TextView question;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewQuestion);

    getRandomQuestion();


    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (answer.getText().toString().equals(questionNumber)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Input True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            getRandomQuestion();
        }
    });
}

private void getRandomQuestion() {
    Random random = new Random();
    questionNumber = String.format("%04d",random.nextInt(10000));
    question.setText(questionNumber);
}
```

Remember to put the getRandomQuestion() below the checker because if you put it above then I believe it will always show the Input Wrong toast unless the first random number will be the same as the second random number.

For example..
You generated a random question in onCreate and let's say it is 1..
Then you put 1 in your editText so you assume that it should show Input True, right? But if you put the getRandomQuestion above the checker.. what will happen is you will generate a random question again then it will be 2..

Then, in your checker.. your answer is 1 then the question is 2.. so it will not be equal.

Comment: You're welcome. :) I'm glad you understand my explanation. ^^

Answer (score 0):

here your solution
put this

```
Random random = new Random();
questionNumber = String.format("%04d",random.nextInt(10000));
question.setText(questionNumber);
```

in the button listner
**EDIT:**

```
 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if (answer.getText().toString().equals(questionNumber)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Input True", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        questionNumber = String.format("%04d",random.nextInt(10000));
        question.setText(questionNumber);

    }
});
```

Comment: I am checking sir